# Cypher Query endless loop

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to `graph databases` and especially `cypher`. I am importing data from my `csv`. Below is the sample I pulled for some `country data` and added the `cities` and `states`. Now I was pushing the data for `areas`

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
"file:///X:/loc.csv" as csvRow
MATCH (ct:city {poc:csvRow.poc})
MERGE (loc:area {eoc: csvRow.eoc, name:csvRow.loc_nme, name_wr:replace(csvRow.loc_nme," ","")})
MERGE (loc)-[:exists_inside]->(ct)
```

I've already pushed city and country data using the same query and built a relation between them too.

But when I try to create the `areas` inside the `city` it just keeps going, there is no stopping it. (15 mins have passed).

> There are 7000 cities in the data I've got from the internet and 90k areas inside those cities.

Is it just taking time or have I messed up with the query.

[image: The Explain]

**After the Update**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
"file:///X:/loc.csv" as csvRow
MATCH (ct:city {poc:csvRow.poc})
MERGE (loc:area {eoc: csvRow.eoc, name:csvRow.loc_nme, name_wr:replace(csvRow.loc_nme," ","")})
MERGE (loc)-[:exists_inside]->(ct)
```

Comment: Can you run an EXPLAIN of the query and add the query plan here, after expanding all elements of the plan?

Comment: @InverseFalcon can you guide me through the process?

Comment: Here's the [profiling developer reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/). Since your query isn't finishing, use EXPLAIN, which will just generate the query plan and not execute the query. If you can expand all elements of the plan, then screenshot it and add it to your question, then we might be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I've updated the question

Comment: try creating the nodes first and then creating the relationships. and use `WITH` for the variables to pass down so that it reduces cardinality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your query plan shows NodeByLabelScans and filters are being used to find your nodes, which means that every time you match or merge to a node, it has to scan all nodes with the given labels and perform property access on all of them to find the nodes you're looking for.

You need to [add indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) (or unique constraints, depending on if the field is supposed to be unique) on the relevant label/property combinations so those lookups will be quick.

So you'll need one on :city(poc), and probably one on :area(eoc), assuming those properties are referring to unique properties.

EDIT

One other big thing I initially missed, you need to add `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` before the LOAD CSV so the load will batch the writes to the db, that should do the trick here.

Comment: it didn't help. I used `CREATE ON :city(eoc)` and likewise. but still when I fire the query and leave it for 30 mins, the window goes black.

Comment: I missed that you weren't using periodic commit for load csv, add that in and it should take care of it.

Comment: Can you please modify the query itself? I am not able to quite understand the edit. I am a little new to graph

Comment: It's literally the same query prepended with `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`. Here's the [entry in the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data)